# If $P$ is invertible and $D$ is diagonal, is $P\overline{D}P^{-1}=\overline{PDP^{-1}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P, D \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $P$ is invertible and $D$ is diagonal. I want to know if $$\overline{PDP^{-1}}=P\overline{D}P^{-1}.$$

For real matrices, of course, this is true, but for complex matrices, is this also true? I cannot prove it so I’m trying to find a counterexample, but so far, all the $2 \times 2$ matrices that I’ve tried show that they are indeed equal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are surely easier counterexamples, but the matrices

$$P = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} -i & i \\ 1 & 1  \end{array} \right] \text{ and } D = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2  \end{array} \right]$$

do the trick.